# Driving in Kenya while in Ontario's graduated licensing system (G1 or G2)

Tags: driving-licenses, kenya

According to [this](http://www.infohub.co.ke/2016/07/foreigner-driving-on-kenyan-roads.html), if you hold a valid Canadian driver's license, you can drive in Kenya (due to both being Commonwealth nations).

However, I was not able to find how this relates to the graduated licensing program of the Canadian province of Ontario.  In Ontario, obtaining the full license for regular automobiles (class G license) takes a minimum of 20 months, during which time after a written test you will hold first a class G1 license for at least 8 or 12 months, then by passing a road test hold a class G2 license for at least 12 months before completing a further road test to obtain the full class G license.  Holders of the G1 license are only permitted to drive certain hours and generally not on freeways and must always be accompanied by an experienced driver (minimum 4 years with class G).  Holders of the G2 license are under more minor restrictions.

If you have one of these intermediate licenses (class G1 or G2), can you drive in Kenya, and if so, are the restrictions the same as in Ontario, or different?

Comment: Please don't lump G1 and G2 together. G1 is basically a "leaner's permit" - you cannot drive alone. G2 is a thing other jurisdictions might not have, and it's possible it would be considered "a drivers license." BTW you must be 18 to drive in Kenya, so if you got your G1 at 16 and G2 at 17, as is typical, the answer would be "you can't drive there" based only on your age, not the license level. https://travel.gc.ca/destinations/kenya

Comment: @KateGregory  Good point about age.  I'm more concerned with the case where an adult has had to go back through the system due to license being long-expired.

Answer (score 1):

In general, learners permits are not valid for operating a motor vehicle outside of the country that issues them as they are not considered full, valid licenses and most countries do not take the time to create rules to allow exemptions for learners permits.

One authoritative source that indicates the non-validity of a learners license abroad is that [the CAA won’t issue IDPs to learner permit holders.](https://www.caa.ca/international-driving-permit/#1472053802928-85d0c595-b90b)